# Create a new page on submit from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, submit

I've created a chained menu using php and a database, following [this tutorial](http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/how-to-create-chained-select-with-php-and-jquery/).

The first table content a list of categories like :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chainmenu_categories` (
    `id_cat` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_cat`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;
```

My second table, the type, like :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `type` (
    `id_type` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_cat` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `destination` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

I managed, once clicking on submit, to redirect to another page by that in my select.php:

```
var result = $("select#type option:selected").html(); 
$("#select_form").submit(function( event ) { 
  var the_url = $("#type").val(); 
  window.location = the_url; 
  event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

and adding this on my select.class.php

```
public function ShowCategory() 
{ 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM chainmenu_categories"; 
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn); 
    $category = '<option value="0">choose...</option>'; 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) 
    { 
        $category .= '<option value="' . $row['id_cat'] . $row['destination']. '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>'; 
    } 
    return $category; 
}
```

So now it redirects each time to a different page depending of the option choose from the menu, like `http://mydomain.com//3` then 4, 5, 6, etc.

But as the page doesn't exist, it redirects to a dead link.

Can someone give me help to create these pages from the chained menu (or have some highlight)? and if possible, some pointer to create the admin interface to allow an admin to add the pages and categories to the chained menu?

I've been trying to start with something which look like:

PHP Code:

```
<?php require('db_config.php');  

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id_type, name FROM type WHERE id_cat=$_POST[id]'); 
$stmt->execute(array(':id_cat' => $_GET['name'])); 
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

However, I don't know if this is good at all.

Comment: so U want to make folder if not exist from database ??

Comment: hm, basicly I'd like to create a "page.php" which can be links to the 'name' from the table "type" of my database.

and, and admin interface, for the purpose of, once the admin login, he can add value in the table "type" of the database, and each time create a page.php related to it,

Don't know if it sounds clear ? I'm struggling to explain that

Comment: page name taken from database ?

Comment: yes, right now, the chained menu redirect to a page, taking in count the id from the list "type" (http://mydomain.com/3 then 4,5,6 etc).

But the page doesnt exsit, I'm trying to figure out how to create these pages, taking in count the id and name value from the database.

And allow to do that via an admin interface... If you have any direction to give me . . . it will be amazing =)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(file_exists($filename.'.php'))
    echo "file : " . $filename.'.php' . " is exist";
else
{
  $file = fopen($filename.'.php',"w");
  $code="here what U want to write inside the new page.php";
  fwrite($file,$code);
  fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Robert,

I'm trying to add the code in my select.class.php but it doesn't seem to work . . .  .

Where should I put it ?

Here is my all select.class.php :

http://codepad.viper-7.com/rybes8

I've been trying a bit everywhere, but doesnt seem to change anything . . . . 

Thank you for your time

Comment: di U change $filename ?

Comment: yes it is my real code, I change filename by $name and didnt work . . .

Comment: and this is my select.php if needed maybe . . . 

http://codepad.viper-7.com/hBJ88k

Comment: there are alot of errors on UR code fix it first and try again

Comment: look this code should tun when insert data into database

Comment: I can not see my error on my code . . . the error they said are because the others includ efile are not includes  . . 

Inthe code you gived me, It should be in the select.class.php or select.php ? And where ? the $filename should be replace by the value of my database 'name' ? or something else ? Really apologies, I'm really starting with that  . . .  really appreciate all your time

Comment: Here it was happening at the moment . . . ( without your code, IF I include your code, the 2nd level of themenu doesnt work anymore :() (eg. in Catagorie Champagne)

http://thinktankaadrl.com/vina/chained/select.php